# phonegap plugin: Torch undefined, even though js file is loaded on android

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I get the following error when trying to use the [TorchPluging](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/Torch):

```
 file:///android_asset/www/web/index.html: Line 12 : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Torch' of undefined
```

I added the plugin to config.xml (I think it has changed from plugins.xml to config.xml in the newer phonegap versions?)

The following is my entire index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Flashlight</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/cordova-2.1.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/Torch.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function turnTorchOn(){

                window.plugins.Torch.turnOn( 
                function() { console.log( "turnOn" ) }                          // success
                ,   function() { console.log( "error" ) });                           // error
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="turnOnButton" name="turnOnButton" > Turn on Flashlight</button>
        <script>

            $('#turnOnButton').click(function(){
                alert("will turn on now");
                turnTorchOn();
                alert("called turnOn done");

            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually isn't that hard to update an older style plugin to one that will work in 2.0.0+. You would need to:

1. Modify the JS to the new cordova.define() style of declaring plugins.
2. Update the package reference to org.apache.cordova.* from com.phonegap.* in the Java code.
3. Make sure you are not calling any deprecated API's.

I've written a couple of blog posts that cover the topic. If you do follow them an update the Torch plugin you should submit a pull request so everyone can enjoy your work.

2.0.0 Plugin - http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.ca/2012/08/so-you-wanna-write-phonegap-200-android.html
Deprecated API's - http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.ca/2012/07/phonegap-android-plugins-sometimes-we.html

Comment: Type in your a short description that it doesn't work in 2.0.0 and I'll hand you correct answer as well :-) (for future people looking it up)

Comment: can it be right that all I need to change is the js "Phonegap" into "Cordova" ?  
When I'm comparing to something like "Analytics" then it's the only difference I my eyes see...?

Comment: and I just merged it. You can now wear the Open Source badge from http://www.nerdmeritbadges.com/products/octocat proudly.